# java currency calculator pausing swtich to give output back to user

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**first question:**
There is a do while loop, within the do section there is a switch. After selection case 1, some calculations are done, two options can result as shown in the If statement. My problem is code runs until the break; then just goes straight back to the menu loop. My question: how do i get the program to print the output for the user, then continue the menu loop?

**Second question:**
In case 1 there are two resulting options, the first being a failed response. from here, how do i get the program to loop back to the start of case 1 to ask for user input again? Even back to the main menu would be fine.

```
public static void showMenu() {
    System.out.print('\u000c');
    System.out.println("1 - Compute Change \n");
    System.out.println("2 - Estimate Feast \n");
    System.out.println("3 - \n");
    System.out.println("4 - \n");
    System.out.println("5 - I'm broke, get me out of here\n");
    System.out.println("Select Option:\n");
}

public StackPost() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Bank of Winterfell");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        showMenu();
        selection = in.nextInt();

        switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            // get input, compute then decision:
            if (something<somethingElse) {
                // false response -
            } else {
                // correct response - system prints out some stuff back to user, back to main
                // menu loop
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            break;

        case 5:
            System.out.println("\nEnding Now\n");
            System.exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Instruction is invalid");
        }
    } while (selection != 5);
}
```

Comment: I can see only one loop here. So what do you mean by _main loop_?

Answer (score 0):

You could print "Press enter to continue" (or whatever you want to give notice of before locking the program), and add a call to Scanner#nextLine() before your `break`. This will lock the progression 'till user presses enter.

```
case 2:
    // Some code here...

    // Done, now show result and tell user to press any key to continue
    System.out.println("Some fancy result from case handle code");
    System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
    in.nextLine();
    break;
```

You could add a while-loop that won't let the code continue 'till whatever input is expected in the first case is acceptable.

```
case 1:
    System.out.println("Some handle that tells user to input something, and what is acceptable");
    String input = null;

    while(!(input = in.nextLine()).equals("something")) {
        System.out.println("Wrong input, try again...");
    }

    // Input is acceptable, now do something with it...
    System.out.println(input);
    System.out.println("Press enter to continue...");
    in.nextLine();
    break;
```

Be aware, in your code, you call `Scanner#nextInt()`, and `#nextInt` doesn't consume the `\n` from pressing enter, and will thus be transferred into the switch case's usage of `#nextLine()`. You could avoid this with `selection = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine())`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use achieve it by:

- For *First question:* Using `return` statement in case of *correct response*.
- For *Second question:* Using `while` loop in *`case 1`*

After implementaing the proposed solution the `StackPost()` method will look like following. You can see the [complete working code here](https://ideone.com/hIwjcN):

```
public static void  StackPost() 
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Bank of Winterfell");
    try(Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in))
    {
        int selection;
        do 
        {
            showMenu();
            selection = in.nextInt();

            switch (selection) 
            {
                case 1:
                    // get input, compute then decision:
                     while(true)
                    {
                        int something = in.nextInt();
                        int somethingElse = in.nextInt();
                        if (!(something<somethingElse)) {
                            // correct response - system prints out some stuff back to user, back to main
                            System.out.println("Print here the result");
                            // menu loop
                            return;
                        }
                    // false response - continue for next iteration in while-loop   
                    }
                    //No need of 'break;' here

                case 2:
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.println("\nEnding Now\n");
                    System.exit(0);

                default:
                    System.out.println("Instruction is invalid");
            }
        } while (selection != 5);
    }
}
```

**Note:** It is best practice to use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) while handling system resources which implements [`AutoCloseable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html) interface.